# Getting rid of unnecessary text Regex

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

Alright so basically what I am having trouble with is this:
I have a string that looks like this

```
<a class="l _HId" href="http://www.cnbc.com/2016/07/28/royal-dutch-shell-second-quarter-net-profit-comes-in-at-118-billion.html" onmousedown="return rwt(this,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;1&#39;,&#39;AFQjCNHzDJMd9KzNaZJKrec-FAMNdP8ujw&#39;,&#39;mb_qkV1ZFbNFLJBX-JNceA&#39;,&#39;0ahUKEwiwmbPolJbOAhVJ6xQKHT1QDFkQqQIIGigAMAA&#39;,&#39;&#39;,&#39;&#39;,event)">Shell sees quarterly profits plummet 70% as low <em>oil price</em> bites</a>
```

which, simplified, looks like that essentially:

```
<a class="l _HId" href="Link" onmousedown="some gibberish">The String that I need <em>I am guessing this is what I searched</em> bites</a>
```

It would have been very helpful if someone new how something like that could be achieved. Any form of help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us what you tried before we help you.

Comment: But do you want to remove the "gibberish"? or do you want to get "The String that I need"?

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2465194) may apply?

Comment: But then again, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/2465194) post makes a good point that my be more applicable to this situation.

Comment: I want to get "The string that I need".
And because I am new to C# (I usually write code in C++) I don't know much and only tried this :  

    MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html, @"<a>./s*(.+?)/s*</a>", RegexOptions.Singleline);

Comment: @PanosPtr Perhaps for future reference (as you seems to have found an answer), put this information upfront into the question. Even considering the HTML-Regex problem, you may have been more likely to get useful answers. Thorough questions get thorough answers. Thanks for the contribution though and I'm glad you found at least some answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this link post answered all my questions:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

It looks like parsing html with RegeX isn't the best Idea.